# 3D Matrix Transformation

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

This is a question that stems from a programming problem I am having, but I do not understand the math behind it. So forgive me if there is some Stack Overflow bleed in my question.

I have an array. It represents points in a 3D space, xyz for 8000 lines. If you graph all the points the shape the points make is a cube. I do not understand the math behind Matrix transforming my array into another shape - say a rhombiod. I've found many online instructions for this work, but none of which I understand - I've not had very many advanced math classes in my day.

I suppose what I'm looking for is a Reddit-style "ELI5" of Matrix transformations. Or the next best thing, if such a thing like this is possible.

An ideal example:

Lets say the array is (Note it is not quite 8,000 lines long but just under):

```
[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,1],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,1,1],
 [1,0,0],
 [1,0,1],
 [1,1,0],
 [1,1,1]]
```

Which draws a cube when graphed. Pick any sort of equivalent length array that will display a rhomboid - what are the steps to transform the cube into the rhomboid?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a linear transformation of the given points. All linear transformations are represented by a matrix, so a matrix of the form:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3\\
b_1&b_2&b_3\\
c_1&c_2&c_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
does the job. If you multiply with the [row-column rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Matrix_multiplication), the matrix by the vectors in the array you obtain, in general, a rhomboid if the determinant of the matrix is not null. If the determinant is null than the cube can be squashed on a plane or on a line.